# mongodb insert from array fails

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, insert, bson

I'm using MongoDB on ubuntu server.
I would like to generate my documents in and store them in an array. After that I would like to insert these documents into my collection, but somehow the collection is always empty. It's important, that the data generation is seperated from the storage for measuring. I'm using javascript for that.
However, that's some code:

```
for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
{                                           
doc = "datetime:" + Math.floor((1262300400+Math.random()%(1356994799-1262300400+1))) + sourceport: " + Math.floor((Math.random()*30000)+2000) ;
myarray[i]=doc;
}

...

for (n=0;n<=myarray.length-1;n++)
    {
        obj_doc = eval('{' + myarray[n] +'}');
        eval('var obj='+myarray[n]);
        obj_doc = '{' + myarray[n] +'}';
        db.mycol.insert(obj_doc);
    }
```

It doesn't even work without the rnd() function.
db.mycol.stats() always returns "count:0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up the docs to insert as objects, not strings and `eval`:

```
for (i=0; i<amount; i++) {                                           
    doc = {
        datetime: Math.floor((1262300400+Math.random()%(1356994799-1262300400+1))),
        sourceport: Math.floor((Math.random()*30000)+2000)
    };
    myarray[i]=doc;
}

...

db.mycol.insert(myarray);
```

Comment: No error occurs, but there are still 0 elements in the collection

Comment: @Tyzak What's `amount` set to when you run this?  I tried this in the mongo shell with `amount = 50` and it did insert 50 docs.

Comment: hm my amount is 100 ... what is about strings? I added a string like mystring: "test" is that okay?

Comment: @Tyzak Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: hm sorry, I tried it with the code above and with an additional item like test: "test" as a string. Both don't work somehow - the count of my collection stats is always:0 ... I don't understand that :<

Comment: and I checked the sharding key, that's correct, too. Furthermore I created a new db and a new collection - the amount of inserted data is always 0 (count:0) - by inserting manually via the shell it works, but not via javascript

Comment: db.mycol.insert(myarray) in a for loop with myarray[i] works somehow - thanks ;>